# Starting Java Webstart App with older installed JRE Version

Tags: java, jnlp

is there any chance to start a jnlp with jre 7_17 while jre 7_45 is the latest version installed on the system?

First i tried it by editing the jnlp file itself and changing the version from 1.5+ to 1.7.0_17. But this wasnt working. After some research, this could be a bug.

Then i tried to start the jnlp file by commandline and the javaws.exe from the bin path of the older jre version. But still the newer one is used.

Are there any chances to have many jres installed and open the different webstart apps with the version which is supported by the supplier ?

thanx
Marcus

Answer (score 0):

You may not start the jnlp file itself with a specific java version - the one installed (and default in the webbrowser) is used to start the jnlp. However you can specify with which java version your application/applet is started afterwards. [Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/developersguide/syntax.html) is a description:

*"The version attribute refers, by default, to a platform version (specification version) of the Java(TM) Platform Standard Edition. Currently defined platform versions are 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5 and 1.6. (A platform version will not normally contain a micro version number; e.g., 1.4.2.)
Exact product versions (implementation versions) may also be specified. by including the href attribute. For example, 1.3.1_07, 1.4.2, or 1.5.0"*

...

You may also use < java ...> instead of < j2se ...>
Furthermore if you have an jnlp based application it should work to manually specify the (full) path to your older java.